# onActivityResult from camera gives null intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

so this was working lovely till yesterday when I upgraded my phone to 5.0.0 and tested the application out in a 5.0.0 emulator. Basically the purpose is to allow the user to take a photo, return it, open it to allow cropping then return it and set it as an imageview.

Everything worked fine before but now the intent in onActivityResult is null.

Here's code:

```
public void takeDisplayPicture(View view) {

    final String TAKE_DISPLAY_PICTURE = "Take Display Picture";

    Log.d(TAKE_DISPLAY_PICTURE, "Clicked");

    try {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        String msg = "Your device doesn't support a camera!";

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    final String RETURN_DISPLAY_PICTURE = "Return Display Picture";

    Log.d(RETURN_DISPLAY_PICTURE, "Returned");

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {

        picUri = data.getData();
        performCrop(picUri);

    } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
        displayPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

}

private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {

    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        String msg = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

With respect to the `null` `Uri`, it is supposed to be `null`. Quoting [the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field.

You do not have `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and so you are supposed to get your image via the poorly-documented `(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");`.

Comment: Would it be more beneficial to do EXTRA_OUTPUT then regarding the code overall? Regarding the CROP intent, why does this work on 4.0 and not 5.0? What is the work around/other method of performing a crop?

Comment: @AlexKnight: "Would it be more beneficial to do EXTRA_OUTPUT then regarding the code overall?" -- if you want full-size images, it is your only option. If all you need is a thumbnail, then your current code is fine, other than expecting a `Uri`. "why does this work on 4.0 and not 5.0?" -- maybe the camera app changed. Nobody with any sense relies on undocumented stuff like that `Intent` action, as there is no requirement that all camera apps (pre-installed, installed from the Play Store, etc.) offer that action.

Comment: @AlexKnight: "What is the work around/other method of performing a crop? " -- read the blog post that I linked to in my question for links to some libraries. Or, look at [this Android Arsenal category](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: Will have a look at those and get back to you. What I want overall is a full-size image (quality wise) that the user can then crop which is then used in the imageView (this is then uploaded to a server via async but thats another story.)

Comment: @AlexKnight: Then you will have to use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and pray. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is easy but is not an especially reliable solution, as you have no control over what that camera app does, and camera app quality varies.

Comment: hmmm okay, so essentially I'd have to build my own image cropping intent to ensure it works across all devices? no worth it for the project I'm doing. What would be the suitable way to catch if the device doesn't have the CROP intent? as currently the app crashes upon return of the null intent.

Comment: @AlexKnight: "so essentially I'd have to build my own image cropping intent to ensure it works across all devices?" -- you would use a library. "What would be the suitable way to catch if the device doesn't have the CROP intent?" -- `ActivityNotFoundException`, though that does not mean that if the activity exists that you will get the results that you expect.

Comment: Sweet, got it working with the android-crop library found here: https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop cheers for the help.